# Prevent navigate the page same to current page when tapping drawer item in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Suppose I have a drawer, and the app already in 'Home' page.

When tapping the 'Settings' item in drawer, it will navigate again to 'Settings'.

How to prevent it, prevent navigate to the page same with current page.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Drawer(
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text("Home"),
            trailing: new Icon(Icons.local_florist),
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new HomePage()));
              Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/', (_) => false);
            },
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text("Search"),
            trailing: new Icon(Icons.search),
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new SearchPage('Search Web')));
            },
          ),
          new Divider(),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text("Settings"),
            trailing: new Icon(Icons.settings),
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new SettingsPage('Settings Center')));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It'll be better if you'll paste some code - how exactly you make this

Comment: Code updated...

Comment: I use pop() to close the drawer after tapping. push() to navigate to the selecting page. And I add this drawer to every page.

Comment: It seems quite a boilerplate. I think it'll be better to make one abstract class with drawer to avoid this copypaste

Comment: And about your question - try to look at this - https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RadioListTile-class.html - maybe using them instead of 'ListTile`s will help. Or you can save current state of your drawer and check it before pushing new route

Comment: I wrapped the drawer into a class already. and use drawer: new drawerEx(), in each Scaffold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fairly simple solution to this would be to simply make the button for the current page disabled. You could make an enum of all the pages and pass in a 'currentPage', and then when you're building the list tiles you could do something like `onTap: currentPage == Pages.Search ? null : () { .... }`

If you want to do something a bit more configurable, you could do something like what I do for my app - for my drawer menu, I have an enum that lists all of the options (i.e. `enum DrawerSections { home, profile, settings, about, logout }` and my drawer class takes a list of sections to show, as I don't want all of the menu sections shown in each case. You could pass in a list of something like DrawerSectionSpec that has a `DrawerSection` and a `bool enabled`.

Comment: I used the first simple to do it. The second is a little complex, I will do it later, cause I'm learning flutter not very long. If you have any samples, It will be much more thankful.